# Color Code Calendar "View" items

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a list of items that includes dates. Is there a way to color code items from my list that will show up in the calendar view? I have been able to color code items in my list using calculated columns ( Danny-Engelman method) in lists view but the color does not roll up into the calendar view.

any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Max

Answer (score 4):

The easy way to do this is through Calendar Overlay.  You can create categories and overlay calendar views based on the category.

Good tutorial is available [here](http://www.degdigital.com/insights/four-easy-steps-to-customized-color-code-calendars-in-sharepoint/) and [here](https://davidlozzi.com/2012/06/20/customize-the-sharepoint-calendar-colors/)

Answer (score 3):

The method I documented: http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How
uses HTML in Calculated Columns, which works since SP2010,

but is undocumented and not supported by MS, it does not work in the Calendar View or any other non-standard View.

Since SP2013 there is CSR (Client Side Rendering) where you use JavaScript to override SPs own presentation.

I have never done anything with Calendar Views

for CSR coding examples here on SO see: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=icsr

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below article to achieve what you needed. Basically create a calculated column with a specified separator and apply formatting based on your condition. This worked for me

http://www.sharepointjunkies.com/color-coded-calendar-sharepoint-online-using-javascript/